# How to transfer bundle data over multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity

How to extract data that bundled in third activity by using onActivityResult(),
i.e. activity A starts Activity B, than Activity B again start Activity C, now we have send bundled data from activity C to activity A.

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityResult() to start  B from A and then use startActivityResult() again to start C from B.

Then set the result Intent and finish C. This will send the result to onActivityResult() of B. Again, set the same result Intent and finish B right from onActivityResult() of B.

This will send the same result to onActivityResult() of A.